# stop alone numbers NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Suppose I have

```
phrase="Boeing777 is very fast because it can goes to 950 kms/hours"
```

My idea is to get rid off only 950 because he is a alone number but I don't want to remove 777 from Boeing. 
And I have :

```
exclude=set('0123456789')
print("".join(ch for ch in phrase if ch not in exclude))

Boeing is very fast because it can goes to  kms/hours
```

And I want :

```
Boeing777 is very fast because it can goes to  kms/hours
```

Comment: you can do this with a regex https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html eg `re.sub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do exactly what you ask, you can use a regular expression, eg:

```
import re

phrase="Boeing777 is very fast because it can goes to 950 kms/hours"

print re.sub(r'\s\d+\s', ' ', phrase)
```

which replaces any pattern of whitespace (`\s`) surrounding one or more (`+`) digits (`\d`) with the string `' '`.

depending on how sophisticated you want this to be you can improve on that regex.

for example you might want to consider what you want to do about the phrase

`phrase="Boeing777 is very fast. it's top speed is 950."`

because 950 is followed there by a `.` you would need a different regex. this is what I thought of in a quick look:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\s)(\d+)(?=\s|\.|,|$)', '', phrase)
```

this checks for whitespace before, and for whitespace, period or comma after, but obviously there is still room for improvement. Not knowing your actual requirements I am going to leave that with you.

Comment: That's pretty insane all right. Use this regexp instead: re.sub(`r"\b\d+\b", " ", phrase)`.

Comment: @alexis yeah, that's better. :) I did think halfway through that the proper way would have been to use \W for punctuation, but I've never used \b so it wasn't in the front of my mind